# I am not a native. Is the following sentence authentic?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to know if you are the only interviewer and do we use English or Chinese for our interview?

Comment: Why do you think it might ***not*** be "authentic"? Unless you can give us something there, the question is Off Topic proofreading.